# How to create a multi line body in C# System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

Tags: c#, email

If create the body property as

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

message.Body ="First Line \n second line";
```

I also tried

```
message.Body ="First Line" + system.environment + "second line";
```

Both of these were ignored when I received the message (using outlook).

Any ideas on how to get mutliple lines? I am trying to avoid html encoding so that the email will play nicer with spam filters.

thanks

Comment: Did you set `message.IsBodyHtml = false` ?

Comment: Did you try changing system.environment to Environment.NewLine?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

As per the comment by drris, if `IsBodyHtml` is set to true then a standard newline could potentially be ignored by design, I know you mention avoiding HTML but try using `<br />` instead, even if just to see if this 'solves' the problem - then you can rule out by what you know:

```
var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.Body = "First Line <br /> second line";
```

You may also just try setting `IsBodyHtml` to `false` and determining if newlines work in that instance, although, unless you set it to `true` explicitly I'm pretty sure it defaults to `false` anyway.

Also as a side note, avoiding HTML in emails is not necessarily any aid in getting the message through spam filters, AFAIK - if anything, the most you do by this is ensure cross-mail-client compatibility in terms of layout. To 'play nice' with spam filters, a number of other things ought to be taken into account; even so much as the subject and content of the mail, who the mail is sent from and where and do they match et cetera. An email simply won't be discriminated against *because* it is marked up with HTML.

Comment: The OP said he wanted to avoid HTML

Comment: He'd like to avoid HTML. So `IsBodyHtml = false` and using newlines, should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 26):

In case you dont need the message body in html, turn it off:

```
message.IsBodyHtml = false;
```

then use e.g:

```
message.Body = "First line" + Environment.NewLine + 
               "Second line";
```

but if you need to have it in html for some reason, use the html-tag:

```
message.Body = "First line <br /> Second line";
```

Comment: It was the IsBodyHtml setting for me. System.Environment.NewLine does not work when IsBodyHtml is set to true

Answer (score 15):

Beginning each new line with two white spaces will avoid the auto-remove perpetrated by Outlook.

```
var lineString = "  line 1\r\n";
linestring += "  line 2";
```

Will correctly display:

```
line 1
line 2
```

It's a little clumsy feeling to use, but it does the job without a lot of extra effort being spent on it.

Comment: This solution is still valid in 7/2021.

Comment: @atheaos You'd think this would have been figured out by now. I'd forgotten about this problem entirely.

Answer (score 5):

I usually like a StringBuilder when I'm working with MailMessage.  Adding new lines is easy (via the AppendLine method), and you can simply set the Message's Body equal to StringBuilder.ToString() (... for the instance of StringBuilder).

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("my content here...");
result.AppendLine(); // break line
```

Comment: I tried a stringbuilder object, and did append line for each line and then assigned the message.body to be equal to the .ToString() method of the string builder. But when the email shows up in outlook it is still all one line. I may have to just use html.

Comment: Actually, I think @Mr. Disappointment might be on to something & probably has the more thoughtful answer.

Comment: That is why my answer above is better since it uses the environments newline, checking which framework is used, so it checks which OS you are using then appending new lines depending on the system. The stringbuilder is great in one aspect: a string never leaves the memory but stacks new strings to it when it is changed while a stringbuilder changes the string that is already in memory, but there is no good solution yet in the .NET framework for it I guess :)

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari `StringBuilder.AppendLine` method internally uses `Environment.NewLine`. See [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,743)

Comment: ah, there you go, I shouldn´t have been so hasty without checking it up

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable IsBodyHTML

```
message.IsBodyHtml = true; //This will enable using HTML elements in email body
message.Body ="First Line <br /> second line";
```

Comment: using html worked best for me in Outlook. When I would turn it off, and use \r\n, or Environment.Newline, It would break whenever there was a line a few characters longer than the one prior. Everything would just get mashed together. Could never figure it out. Using Html, was my work around.

Answer (score 2):

The key to this is when you said

> using Outlook.

I have had the same problem with perfectly formatted text body e-mails.  It's Outlook that make trash out of it.  Occasionally it is kind enough to tell you that "***extra line breaks were removed***".  Usually it just does what it wants and makes you look stupid.

So I put in a terse body and put my nice formatted text in an attachement.  You can either do that or format the body in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
IsBodyHtml = false,
BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
BodyTransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.EightBit
```

If you wish to stick to using \r\n

I managed to get mine working after trying for one whole day!

Comment: Worked perfect for me.  Seems like this should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the verbatim operator "`@`" before your message:

```
message.Body = 
@"
FirstLine
SecondLine
"
```

*Consider that also the distance of the text from the left margin affects on the real distance from the email body left margin..*

Comment: Combination with the (@) and <br /> as in the answer of @Grant Thomas and active 'isBodyHtml" works perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using  a StringBuilder object and use the appendline method. That might work.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but whoever did it likely did because this isn't substantively different from the OP's current solution. He's saying that newlines (which is what `AppendLine` will insert) aren't doing the trick for him.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you don't want to create a html e-mail.
I solved the problem this way :

**Replace \n by \t\n**

The tab will not be shown, but the newline will work.

Answer (score 0):

Today I found the same issue on a Error reporting app. I don't want to resort to HTML, to allow outlook to display the messages I had to do (assuming StringBuilder sb):

`sb.Append("  \r\n\r\n").Append("Exception Time:" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

I realise this may have been answered before. However, i had this issue this morning with `Environment.Newline` not being preserved in the email body. 
The following is a full (Now Working with `Environment.NewLine` being preserved) method i use for sending an email through my program.(The `Modules.MessageUpdate` portion can be skipped as this just writes to a log file i have.) This is located on the main page of my WinForms program.

```
    private void MasterMail(string MailContents)
    {
        Modules.MessageUpdate(this, ObjApp, EH, 3, 25, "", "", "", 0, 0, 0, 0, "Master Email - MasterMail Called.", "N", MainTxtDict, MessageResourcesTxtDict);

        Outlook.Application OApp = new Outlook.Application();
        //Location of email template to use. Outlook wont include my Signature through this automation so template contains only that.
        string Temp = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + ResourceDetails.DictionaryResources("SigTempEmail", MainTxtDict);

        Outlook.Folder folder = OApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts) as Outlook.Folder;

        //create the email object.
        Outlook.MailItem TestEmail = OApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(Temp, folder) as Outlook.MailItem;

        //Set subject line.
        TestEmail.Subject = "Automation Results";

        //Create Recipients object.
        Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)TestEmail.Recipients;

        //Set and check email addresses to send to.
        Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("EmailAddressToSendTo");
        oRecip.Resolve();

        //Set the body of the email. (.HTMLBody for HTML Emails. .Body will preserve "Environment.NewLine")
        TestEmail.Body = MailContents + TestEmail.Body;
        try
        {
            //If outlook is not open, Open it.
            Process[] pName = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK.EXE");
            if (pName.Length == 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE");
            }

            //Send email
            TestEmail.Send();

            //Update logfile - Success.
            Modules.MessageUpdate(this, ObjApp, EH, 1, 17, "", "", "", 0, 0, 0, 0, "Master Email sent.", "Y", MainTxtDict, MessageResourcesTxtDict);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            //Update LogFile - Fail.
            Modules.MessageUpdate(this, ObjApp, EH, 5, 4, "", "", "", 0, 0, 0, 0, "Master Email - Error Occurred. System says: " + E.Message, "Y", MainTxtDict, MessageResourcesTxtDict);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (OApp != null)
            {
                OApp = null;
            }
            if (folder != null)
            {
                folder = null;
            }
            if (TestEmail != null)
            {
                TestEmail = null;
            }
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
```

You can add multiple recipients by either including a "; " between email addresses manually, or in one of my other methods i populate from a Txt file into a dictionary and use that to create the recipients email addresses using the following snippet.

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in EmailDict)
        {
            Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(kvp.Value);
            RecipientList += string.Format("{0}; ", kvp.Value);
            oRecip.Resolve();
        }
```

I hope at least some of this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.` before `\r\n` makes it work if the original string before `\r\n` has no `.`

Other characters may work. I didn't try.

With or without the three lines including IsBodyHtml, not a matter.

Answer (score 0):

This was getting very frustrating for me because I'm using IsBodyHtml=false and I'm just sending plain text and MOST of the time, the newlines are being honored, but not always.

Outlook has a setting that is on by default that will remove extra line breaks. I'm not 100% sure how it determines which line breaks are "Extra" and which belong there, but from some info I found online, it appears that the length of the line may have something to do with it. I guess old email standards were to limit the length of any given line to 78 characters. Now that we have larger monitors, etc. that is no longer the case, but some clients still try to be backward compatible and detect when they get emails that use the old standard and then remove those lines.

Obviously, the easiest way to deal with this is to turn that setting off:

File -> Options -> Mail -> "Message format" section -> uncheck the "Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages" box

But this may not be an option for various reasons, so the next best thing is to get Outlook to decide this isn't an "Extra" line break so that it won't remove it.  I've managed to do this by padding my individual lines with blank spaces to make the length over that 78 char limit.

Here is an example:

```
private void AddToEmail(string message) =>
    _mailMessageStringBuilder.AppendLine(message.PadRight(80));
```

It's not my favorite, but it seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

Something that worked for me was simply separating data with a `:`

`message.Body = FirstLine + ":" + SecondLine;`

I hope this helps