# StringBuilder.AppendLine() does not make a new line

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, email, stringbuilder

I am generating an email when an error occurs. I am using `StringBuilder.AppendLine()` and `StringBuilder.AppendLine(String)` to build up the body of the email, however the body of my email appears as one very long line with no line breaks.

For example:

```vb
Dim ErrorsStringBuilder As New StringBuilder
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("Status : {0}  Message : {1}", Results.Status, Results.ErrorMessage))
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("Failed : {0}  Total : {1}", Results.FailedCount, Results.TotalCount))
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine("Batch #: " & Results.BatchNumber)
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine()
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine("Individual Errors:")
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine()
For Each FailedRecord .......
  ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("Failed Record ID : {0}  Message : {1}", FailedRecord.ID, FailedRecord.ErrorText))
Next
```

This is the description from MSDN for `.AppendLine()` and `.AppendLine(String)` respectively.

> Appends the default line terminator to the end of the current
>   StringBuilder object.
>
> Appends a copy of the specified string followed by the default line
>   terminator to the end of the current StringBuilder object.

My question is: *why* is there no line break? *Why* is the default line terminator not being applied? Am I misunderstanding the description?

ps. I did look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155801/why-does-stringbuilder-appendline-not-add-a-new-line-with-some-strings) but there is no explaination to why.

and I know that I can use `System.Environment.NewLine` or `"\n"` to get linebreaks.

Comment: set `mail.IsBodyHtml = false;` in your vb.net code

Comment: does it work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your email body is of type `HTML` but you are rendering `simple text` -

If you really want it to be `simple text` then in your email object set `IsBodyHtml = false` it will render new lines without modifying your StringBuilder code  -

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
```

If you want HTML only then try adding after every line -

```
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine("<br />");
```

Actually you are trying to build HTML output.

In HTML if you write -

```
<html>
<body>
Hi,

How are you?
</body>
</html>
```

It would result in -

```
Hi, How are you?
```

To make it work, you should enclose these two statements in to two different block elements -

In this case I am using paragraph -

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Hi,</p>

<p>How are you?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

now this will result in -

```
Hi,

How are you?
```

In your case you need to figure out HTML to render required output. Otherwise use `<br />` as a workaround.

Example for HTML with `<p>` tag -

```
Dim ErrorsStringBuilder As New StringBuilder
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("<p>Status : {0}  Message : {1}</p>", Results.Status, Results.ErrorMessage))
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("<p>Failed : {0}  Total : {1}</p>", Results.FailedCount, Results.TotalCount))
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine("<p>Batch #: </p>" & Results.BatchNumber)
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine()
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine("<p>Individual Errors:</p>")
ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine()
For Each FailedRecord .......
  ErrorsStringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("<p>Failed Record ID : {0}  Message : {1}</p>", FailedRecord.ID, FailedRecord.ErrorText))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears as one long line your e-mail message is most probably set to display as HTML, not plain text. In HTML you have to use `<br/>` for line breaks.

You could try `ErrorsStringBuilder.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + "<br/>")` at the end of your code to add the HTML line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HTML format for the email body, wrap your ErrorsStringBuilder output inside `<pre>...</pre>` tags to preserves both spaces and line-breaks and use fixed width fonts to maintain formatting.