# How can I add a blank line to my StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, splistitem

It is a known "issue" that doing this:

```
sb.AppendLine();
```

...will not add a blank line, as one would expect (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155801/why-does-stringbuilder-appendline-not-add-a-new-line-with-some-strings), for instance).

However, it is commonly believed that this will work:

```
sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
```

...but it's not working for me. I've got this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfListItems.Count; i++)
{
    sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
    lc = listOfListItems[i];
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format(@"<p>Request date is {0}; Payee Name is {1}; Remit Address or Mail Stop is {2}; Last 4 of SSN or ITIN is {3}; 204 Submitted or on file is {4}; Requester Name is {5}; Dept or Div Name is {6}; Phone is {7}; Email is {8}</p>",
        lc.li_requestDate, lc.li_payeeName, lc.li_remitAddressOrMailStop, lc.li_last4SSNDigitsOrITIN, lc.li_204SubmittedOrOnFile, lc.li_requesterName, lc.li_deptDivName, lc.li_phone, lc.li_email));
}
```

All the data is being added to the StringBuilder, and then to the form that gets generated, but there are no spaces between the list items - the "sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine)" is appending nothing.

What must I do to force a line between the individual list item outputs?

Comment: According to the post you're referencing, `sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)` is the trick (Append, not AppendLine)

Comment: @AdamPlocher `StringBuilder.AppendLine` just calls `Append(Environment.NewLine)`. Really, I think something else is wrong here - `AppendLine` always worked for me.

Comment: @Lucas Yeah I see that [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,c0554798fe05ba4f).  Was just pointing out that his question is referencing AppendLine instead of Append in that scenario.  I've never had problems with AppendLine(), either but it definitely seems like an issue that exists sometimes...

Comment: @Adam I don't think there's an issue, Praveen probably guessed what's going wrong for the OP: HTML whitespace folding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The StringBuilder.AppendLine does add a \r\n to the end of the string. You do not need to explicitly add another statement like StringBuilder.AppendLine(System.Environment.NewLine). You can cross check this by converting your string returned from a StringBuilder to an Array of chars, where you can see the newlines.

In your example, it looks like you are trying to display the output in HTML (looking at the p tag in your string) and the newline is not visible in your HTML. In order to achieve this, you may want to add a br to your string.

```
sb.AppendLine("<br/>");
```

A carriage return (\r\n) has no meaning within HTML tags.

Answer (score 2):

*Adding to this question despite its age because it is the first result from google.)*

Other options for displaying white space:

1. Wrap the `<p></p>` tag in a `<pre> </pre>` tag like:

   ```cs
   sb.Append("<pre><p>").Append(aStringVariable).AppendLine("</p></pre>");
   ```
2. Assign a css class to that element:

   ```html
   <p class="preserveWhiteSpace">
   ```

   ```css
   .preserveWhiteSpace{
   white-space: pre;
   }
   ```

   or, if you want line breaks AND wrapping without overflowing the object's container:

   ```css
   .preserveWhiteSpace{
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   }
   ```
3. If you are formatting html for an email and the email client is not behaving:

   ```cs
   sb.AppendLine("<p style="background-color: white; color: white;">.</p>")
   ```

   This is the hackiest option, but the html support in email clients tend to use really old html/css standards...