# the email body removing all lines break (windows form )

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, smtp, outlook-2013

i'm generating a simple email in windows form application  using the

```
 System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
```

and i can't add new line to email body ,
 I've tried almost all possible things so far, like :

```
Environment.Newline

"\n" , "\t" , "\r\r"

 Regex.Replace(body, @"(?<!\t)((?<!\r)(?=\n)|(?=\r\n))", "\t", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: i can't add new line to email body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email body is actually read as an HTML. So you should use HTML tags to accomplish your body design.

Use `<br>` tag for changing the line.

`MailMessage.IsBodyHtml` must be set to `true` to render it as an HTML email.

Answer (score 0):

The linked response below might help.

[How to create a multi line body in C# System.Net.Mail.MailMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020469/how-to-create-a-multi-line-body-in-c-sharp-system-net-mail-mailmessage)