# System.Environment.NewLine inside an smtp message body will not have any effect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following inside my asp.net mvc web application, where i have a string named scan.Description that stores details about the action execution:-

```
foreach(var c in Assets){
//code goes here
     scan.Description = scan.Description + c.ScanResult + " \"" + System.Environment.NewLine;
//code goes here
}
```

then at the end of this action method , i will send the final scan.Description string by email as follow:-

```
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, "*****"))
            {
                mail.Subject = "scan report generated";


                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            System.Text.StringBuilder mailBody = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            mailBody.AppendLine("<span style='font-family:Segoe UI'><b>Hi </b><b></b> <br/><br/>");
            mailBody.AppendLine(scan.Description );
            mailBody.AppendLine("<br/><br/><div style='color:#f99406;font-weight:bold'>scanning Management </div> <br/> <div style='color:#f99406;font-weight:bold'>Best Regards</div></span>");

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpIP"];
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            mail.Body = mailBody.ToString();
            //    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(from, "BetherealwayS$1");
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            //   smtp.Credentials = networkCredential;
            smtp.Port = Int32.Parse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"]);


            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
```

but the problem i am facing is that the email body will not have any `System.Environment.NewLine` and it will be a single paragraph ?

Comment: You're writing an HTML mail... Whitespace doesn't do anything there. Use `<br/>`. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020469/how-to-create-a-multi-line-body-in-c-sharp-system-net-mail-mailmessage). Try to [search sometimes before asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1146775/john-g?tab=questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.NewLine` doesn't mean "this will now magically work everywhere as a new line". It simply means the newline sequence for a particular OS/hosted environment.

In your case, since you're sending a HTML message, you need to use HTML for newlines - that is, either `<p>...</p>` or `<br />` depending on what exact kind of new line you're talking about.

Expecting `Environment.NewLine` to work for such a scenario is like expecting it to work for e.g. HTTP headers (the correct one is *always* CRLF, no matter the environment), or in a custom binary format.